# How do I find the marginal distribution with this summation/series?

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be a Poisson(2) and $Y$ be Binomial(10,3/4) random variables, If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $P(XY=0)$ is

I thought of using transformation to find the distribution of $XY$ so I let $U=XY, V=Y$ with$|j|=\frac{1}{v}$ hence the transformed bivariate distribution from $$f(x,y)=\frac{e^{-2}2^x}{x!}.\binom{10}{y}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^y\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{10-y} \text{is} f(u,v)=\frac{e^{-2}2^{\frac{u}{v}}}{\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)!}.\binom{10}{v}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^v\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{10-v}\frac{1}{v}$$ now I don't know how to find distribution of $U$ with it as unable to solve this $$\sum_{v=1}^{10}\frac{e^{-2}2^{\frac{u}{v}}}{\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)!}.\binom{10}{v}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^v\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{10-v}\frac{1}{v}$$ any suggestions? May be there is some other method which I don't know about.

Comment: For a product to be 0 one of the variables must equal 0... use this to avoid the XY distribution calculation.

Comment: @N74 you saved a life today:P just one more thing should I take all three cases that is when X=0,y=0 and both are 0.

Comment: Remember that the area of two overlapping figures is the sum of their two areas less the area of their intersection.

Comment: Insightful, Oh I need to use this $P(X=0)+P(y=0)-P(X=0andY=0)$ right?

Comment: You can further expand your expression

Comment: Sorry didn't get it what else do I need to do?

Comment: By expand further did you mean this P(X=0,Y=y)+ P(X=x,Y=0) -P(X=0,Y=0) where P(X=0,Y=y) is calculated by $\sum_{y=1}^{10}f(y)$ but it will be equal to 1 so.

Comment: The variables are independent... the probability of the intersection of two independent events is the product of their probabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a change of variables; we have
$$\{XY=0\} = \{X=0\}\cup\{X\ne0,Y=0\}, $$
and so by independence,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(XY=0) &= \mathbb P(X=0) + \mathbb P(X\ne0)\mathbb P(Y=0)\\
&= e^{-2} + (1-e^{-2})\left(\frac14\right)^{10}\\
&= e^{-2} + (1-e^{-2})2^{-20}.
\end{align}